# Solving for a ridge penalty given a fitted model

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

This is kind of embarrassing; I once knew this stuff, and I've forgotten it.  I've got a fitted ridge regression:

$$
\hat\beta = \left(X'X+\lambda\right)^{-1}X'y
$$
X is n by k

y is n by 1

$\lambda$ is k by k

$\hat\beta$ is k by 1

The inverted matrix is invertible.

How do I solve for lambda?  I've got the data $X,y$ and the parameters $\hat\beta$

Edit:  potentially useful bit of information:  ridge penalties are usually a vector multiplied by an identity matrix.  But in this problem I can't assume that the off-diagonals are zero.

Edit2:  So, the answer should have been obvious.  A fitted model implies an estimated $V_p$ matrix.  Divide by estimated dispersion parameter and any degrees of freedom correction, and you've got $(X'X+\lambda)^{-1}$.  invert and get $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $\lambda$ is a diagonal matrix.

$$
\lambda \hat\beta + X'X\hat\beta = X'y
$$

You get:
$$
\lambda_i= \frac1{ \hat\beta_i}
\left\{\sum_k X_{ki}y_k - \sum_{k,l} X_{ki}X_{kl}\hat\beta_l\right\}
$$as long as $\hat\beta_i\neq 0$.

Comment: I got as much with pencil and paper.  But how do I isolate lambda?

Comment: look at one coordinate  $\hat\beta_i\neq 0$.

Comment: what do you mean by coordinate?

Comment: one entry of the vector $\hat \beta$.

Comment: Now I'm confused in a different way.  Say $\hat\beta_1$ = 2.  This would give me $\lambda = X'y*.5-X'X$.  What does that even mean?  $\hat\beta$ is a vector, and that gives me a matrix for one single beta.  I think my problem is that I forget something relatively basic in matrix algebra, and it remains an unknown unknown.

Comment: under your hypothesis, $\lambda = (X'y)_1 - (X'X\hat\beta)_1$ ! every term are matrices products resulting in a vector. You are interested in the first entry of this vector.

Comment: look at my last edit.

Comment: I still don't follow.  What are the k subscripts?  Columns in the original $X$?  How could that subscript $y$?  And unless I'm missing something, the output of your answer doesn't yield a k x k matrix.  My $\lambda$ is a matrix, and there are different smoothing penalties for different terms.

Comment: ok. I thought that $\lambda$ was a diagonal matrix. If it is a diagonal matrix, you can find the values as long as $\hat\beta_i$ is never $0$. If it is not, I don't see a way to do this.